# Python While/For loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

how can I make this into a while loop and output the same thing????

```
for x in range(56,120) :
    if (x < 57) :
          summation = 0
    summation = x + summation
    if (x == 119) :
          print (“Sum of integers from 56 to 120 is”, summation)
```

Comment: this assignment is clearly building up to the big reveal `sum(range(56,120))` also keep in mind `range(x,y)` really just goes to `y-1`

Answer (score 1):

```
summation = 0
start_val = 56
stop_val  = 120
while start_val < stop_val:
    summation += start_val
    start_val += 1
print summation
```

Comment: or if you only have to solve this problem, you can be really cool, and do it without loops: (120*121/2)-(55*56/2) : http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods, but one of them is:

```
x = 56
while x < 120:
    ...
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
x = 56
while x < 120:
    sum += x
    x += 1
print(sum)
```

peace!

Comment: Can you help me write code that prints 5 random even numbers between 15 and 35?

Comment: it's very easy: use random.randint() and a while loop