# Pygame function stopping after 5 "yes" presses

Tags: python, while-loop, keyboard, pygame

What I am struggling with is getting a pygame program to stop my function after 5 presses of the "y" key in a previous function.

I am creating a program in pygame for a study with participants. I have created a function that displays a sentence on the screen, each sentence taken from a row in a dataframe. Whether that sentence is true or not according to a given participant, the "y" or "n" key will be pressed and is recorded in a new column in the dataframe.

Right now my function is iterating over all 100 sentences in the dataframe. I would like it to stop iterating after the "y" key has been pressed 5 times.

In getting the response from the keyboard, I have written:

```
def getResponse(trialNum):
    while True:
        sentence = pygame.event.wait()
        if sentence.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.gameExit = True
        if sentence.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if sentence.key == pygame.K_y:
                keyname = 'yes'
                **yesCount = len(pygame.key.get_pressed())
                break
            if sentence.key == pygame.K_n:
                keyname = 'no'
                break
        screen.fill((white))
```

The row with the asterisk (*) indicates my attempt to count the number of times the "y" key has been pressed, which I had hoped to refer to in the following function:

Starting the program:

```
def start():
    screen.fill(white)
    # trials loop
    start_val = 0
    stop_val = 5
        while start_val < stop_val:
                for trial in range(0,numEvents): #specifies number of events
        showOneEvent(trial)
    end()
```

I have tried to go to [this Question about while-for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619272/python-while-for-loop)
and have been unsuccessful. Can someone please let me know what I am missing syntactically in defining the program to stop after I have pressed the "yes" button 5 times?

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use `</br>` for code formatting. Highlight it all in one block and use `ctrl` + `k`, or click the `{}` button in the editor. I just spent time editing all that out to be beaten to the edit by one line by zvone, so that's using quite a bit of time up.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm a bit curious as to how you invoke/call `getResponse()`? It's rare (if at all) that the `pygame.event.wait()` is place in a function like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your while loop try adding a break statement to exit the loop.

```
while start_val < stop_val:
            for trial in range(0,numEvents): #specifies number of events
            if (yesCount == 5)
                 break;
showOneEvent(trial)
```

you could also try adding to your start_val since you're not reusing it.

```
while start_val < stop_val:
                for trial in range(0,numEvents): #specifies number of events
                     start_val = start_val + 1
showOneEvent(trial)
```